# Is there of overriding the ion-view ion-title font colour across the board using the scss?

Tags: css, sass

I'm sure there's probably a way of overriding the font colour across the board but I'm not sure of the syntax - I imagine its easily possible in the scss file - Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use this in css

```
*{
    color:#123456;
}
```

to apply the css to all text

```
*{
    color:#123456 !important;
}
```

and this if you really want it everywhere although it is not suggested.

Comment: Its really just on the ion-title within the ion-view that I want it overridden. I would have thought there would be something like ion-view/ion-title .font{ color: #12345;}